# How to reset marquee progress bar

Tags: winapi, mfc

I am running the sample code from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387183.aspx).

```
// Turn the marquee animation on or off. 
void CCProgressCtrl_s1Dlg::OnSetmarqueeOn()
{
    m_progressCtrl.SetMarquee(TRUE, nMarqueeInterval);
}

void CCProgressCtrl_s1Dlg::OnSetmarqueeOff()
{
    m_progressCtrl.SetMarquee(FALSE, nMarqueeInterval);
}
```

This works but the problem is when marquee is off, the progress bar stays frozen at the instance. So if the moving light was in the middle at the time it will just freeze in that position. I want to reset the marquee when I turn it off but couldn't find any function for that. I tried SetPos(0) but that doesn't help either. Is there a way to reset the marquee progress bar once it has been sprang into action?

Comment: Proper UI design is to *hide* a marquee style progress bar when it is no longer useful.  You can of course re-create it if you really want to.

Comment: @HansPassant That's what I am doing at the moment to come around it but I am displaying the progress on an existing dialog, not a popup dialog and there is empty space if I hide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the ProgressBar's `PBS_MARQUEE` window style, such as with `CWnd::ModifyStyle()`, before you can then change the position to whatever value you want.  Enable the `PBS_MARQUEE` style only when you are in marque mode, and disable it when not.

```
void CCProgressCtrl_s1Dlg::OnSetmarqueeOn()
{
    m_progressCtrl.ModifyStyle(0, PBS_MARQUEE);
    m_progressCtrl.SetMarquee(TRUE, nMarqueeInterval);
}

void CCProgressCtrl_s1Dlg::OnSetmarqueeOff()
{
    m_progressCtrl.SetMarquee(FALSE, nMarqueeInterval);
    m_progressCtrl.ModifyStyle(PBS_MARQUEE, 0);
    m_progressCtrl.SetPos(0);
}
```